# Does the flight time when booking a holiday online show the time you arrive in that country and its time zone?

Tags: air-travel, timezones

I was wondering whether the time shown is the time I would be arriving in France so its time zone etc.

I know France is an hour ahead so not sure if I'm right in my assumption... It would be useful to know as I plan on traveling to the States and other European countries soon as well.

[image: time of travel and arrival]

[image: time of travel and arrival]

Comment: If you compare the arrival and departure times with the "total duration", you'll see that they must both be in the respective local times: Paris is one hour ahead of London.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally yes, airlines will list the departure and arrival time of a flight in the timezone of the departing/arriving city. I am not aware of an airline who lists the departure and arrival time to all be from one timezone.